# Is there any gameplay difference between Coco and Crash?

Tags: crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy

After the first boss in *Crash Bandicoot* (in the *Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy*) you're able to swap to Crash's sister Coco.

So far it seems like both have the same abilities and movement/attack speed. Is there any difference between them at all, like locked level parts for either of them? Or is it just a cosmetic choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a cosmetic choice - Crash and Coco share the same physics. While some levels specify that you have to play with either Crash or Coco, you don't have to play a level with both Coco and Crash to be able to get everything in it.

Answer (score -2):

Coco moves faster than Crash, but Crash's spin thing is longer. You'll notice the differences, but they're not huge.

Comment: Your answer directly contradicts the accepted one and general knowledge. That's fine -- maybe everyone is wrong -- but you're going to have to prove you're right with some form of evidence.